# Angular6: preserve query params inside canActivate while navigating

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, angular-routing

I am using Auth guard to check login and inside canActivate I am routing to log in page if a user is not logged in but while redirecting I am losing all the query params. I want to preserve all the query params for which I tried `{ queryParamsHandling: "preserve", }` but it doesn't work here

```
 canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): boolean {

    let url: string = state.url;
    return this.checkLogin(url, route);
  }

  checkLogin(url: string, route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    if (this.common.isUserLoggedIn()) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(["/login"], { queryParamsHandling: "preserve" });
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you try with `{ queryParamsHandling: "merge" })` instead of `preserve` ?

Comment: Yes it did not work

Answer (score 0):

try returning urlTree instead of boolean on else.

```
canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): boolean | UrlTree {

    let url: string = state.url;
    return this.checkLogin(url, route);
  }

  checkLogin(url: string, route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean | UrlTree {
    if (this.common.isUserLoggedIn()) {
      return true;
    } else {
     return this.router.createUrlTree(["/login"], {queryParamsHandling: "preserve" });

    }
  }
```

Comment: Property 'canActivate' in type 'AuthGuardService' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'CanActivate'.
boolean | UrlTree' is not assignable to type '(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean>'.

Comment: I had the same issue, fixed it by passing query params explicitly, so instead of
`return this.router.createUrlTree(["/login"], {queryParamsHandling: "preserve" });`
I wrote

`return this.router.createUrlTree(["/login"], { queryParams: route.queryParams,});`